# How write php script to remove line that have some data in line duplicate with other line in file. when each line in text file separate by colon

Tags: php

I have data in text file separate by colon like

3306250027:JOHN:Male:Manager
3306250028:JOHN:Male:Manager
3306250029:JOHN:Male:Employee

I want to use line 1 and ignore line 2 that have column 2 and 4 duplicated and do nothing with line 3. The out put that I want

3306250027:JOHN:Male:Manager
3306250029:JOHN:Male:Employee

I try to use array_unique() but I don't know what to do, some from my code

```
$lines = file('file.txt');
$result = array_unique($lines, SORT_REGULAR);
```

Comment: It is always best to show us some code or it looks like you jsut want us to code for you

Comment: Are you sure you want to remove Both line 1 and 2? Do you not want to leave one of those lines in the file and just remove the duplicated one

Comment: sorry I jus want to use only line one and ignore line 2

Comment: This is quite easy if there are only a few rows in the file and if the duplicates will always be consecutive. Is that the case?

Comment: some file the duplicate line not consecutive and have a thousand of lines

Comment: Then I would start by researching a sort, PHP has many sort functions available [Start here in the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to reduce the list to one value for each name/title combination, you can group the lines by those two values. Here's an example of one way to do that:

```
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    list(,$name,,$title) = explode(':', $line);
    $groups[$name][$title] = $groups[$name][$title] ?? $line;
}
```

By setting `$groups[$name][$title]` to the value `$groups[$name][$title] ?? $line`, we ensure that only the first value for each name/title combination will be used. This will result in an array like this:

```
[
    "JOHN": [
        "Manager": "3306250027:JOHN:Male:Manager",
        "Employee": "3306250029:JOHN:Male:Employee"
    ]
]
```

After you have the data in that grouped form, you just need to extract the unique values back out of it for your result. That's pretty easy to do with `array_walk_recursive`.

```
array_walk_recursive($groups, function($line) use (&$result) {
   $result[] = $line; 
});
```